# Why is .filter not removing null values from my Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to filter out unnecessary null values from my LinkedHashMap. However it isn't actually removing these values.

Variable declaration

```
Map<String,Object> dataDictionary = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Small section of what is being returned when i sysout.print(dataDictionary) after using the filter method.

```
[industryCodes=<null>,regionCodes=<null>,andKeywords=false,id= 
<null>,resultsPerPage=20,keywords=<null>,omitKeywords=<null>}
```

Java code

```
dataDictionary= dataDictionary.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue()!=null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Expecting the null values and their keys to be removed but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: you will have to provide something that we could test against, as it is, it's impossible to answer...  some _individial_ properties from your `value` are null, but not the value itself, is it?

Comment: This is not how a `null` would be printed so I guess this is an instance overriding `toString` that print one variable that is `null`, the instance itself is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is totally unnecessary. The following is enough to remove all `null` values:

```
dataDictionary.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

No need for streams and such.

Edit: Here is the code I've tested it with:

```
Map<String,Object> dataDictionary = new LinkedHashMap<>();
dataDictionary.put("industryCodes", null);
dataDictionary.put("regionCodes", "test");
dataDictionary.put("omitKeywords", null);
dataDictionary.put("resultsPerPage", 21);
dataDictionary.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
System.out.println(dataDictionary);
```

Output: `{regionCodes=test, resultsPerPage=21}`

With the `removeIf` line commented out I get: `{industryCodes=null, regionCodes=test, omitKeywords=null, resultsPerPage=21}`

Seems to be working for me.

Maybe there is something wrong with your values and they actually aren't null?

Edit2: As suggested by Holger, before Java 8 you can use the following:

```
dataDictionary.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Comment: I think Amongalen's answer is correct. Maybe the value is not `null` but something with a `toString()` returning `"<null>"`.

Comment: @PremiumAluminium Added testing code to my answer, check it out.

Comment: I think you might be right about the values not actually being null.

Comment: Or, before Java 8: `dataDictionary.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));`